# Div height not fully stretching to 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a div that is set to 100% height, and it renders perfectly, yet I have two divs within it that will not stretch to 100%. For reference here is the css:

```
#page{
    background-color: #4C1B1B;
    width:85%;
    height:500px
    margin:auto;
    min-height:100%;

}

#pageleft{
    width:15%;
    float:left;
    border:3px solid #B9121B;
    border-left:0px;
    padding: 1% 2% 0 2%;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 50px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
    height:100%;
}

#pageright{
    width:75%;
    float:right;
    border:3px solid #B9121B;
    height:100%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 25px;
    -moz-border-radius: 25px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    margin:0% 3% 0% 0%;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Links are great, but you should always include the relevant code within the question.  That way if those links go away, the question can still be useful.

Comment: @Montagne You are right, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your CSS:

```
#page {
    background-color: #4C1B1B;
    width:85%;
    height:500px;  <--- this should be 100%
    margin:auto;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

You have set the height of the parent div to `500px`.  So your elements are 100% of that.  Change this to `height: 100%`.

Comment: In other words, you will need to set the height of `html` and `body` to `100%`.

Comment: @Wex No, he already set the height of the html and the body.  He needs to set the height of `#page` to 100% instead of 500px.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't see that while debugging.